# Mobile nav buttons don't appear

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

I built a website using WordPress and the Bootstrap framework. Everything displays and functions properly on my PC. But when I open it up on my smartphone (or resize the browser window) to test the mobile nav, the buttons don't appear when I click (or tap) the button that appears on smaller screens.

I don't think it's a CSS issue from what I can tell, and the only other thing I can think of is a possible JQuery script conflict.

Website [Link](http://www.larsenhomeimprovements.com).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a conflict with one of the WordPress plugins currently in use on the site.  The plugin in question is [Easy Testimonials](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-testimonials/).  More specifically, a particular option within the plugin settings that gives you the option of disabling the Cycle2 Javascript file that comes with the plugin.  Having this disabled caused my navigation to not appear on mobile.  Once I enabled it, everything worked fine.